# Getting this error with Flutter ios pod install when I added Google Mobile Ad SDK. Any thoughts on how to fix?

Tags: ios, flutter

Getting this error with Flutter ios pod install when I added Google Mobile Ad SDK. Any thoughts on how to fix?

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "nanopb":
  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 0.14.4, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (~> 6.33.0) was resolved to 6.33.0, which depends on
        FirebaseFirestore (~> 1.18.0) was resolved to 1.18.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 1.30906.0)

    google_mobile_ads (from `.symlinks/plugins/google_mobile_ads/ios`) was resolved to 0.0.1, which depends on
      Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK (= 7.69.0) was resolved to 7.69.0, which depends on
        GoogleAppMeasurement (~> 7.0) was resolved to 7.3.0, which depends on
          nanopb (~> 2.30906.0)
```

Flutter Doctor:
Flutter 2.0.0 • channel unknown • unknown source
Framework • revision 60bd88df91 (6 weeks ago) • 2021-03-03 09:13:17 -0800
Engine • revision 40441def69
Tools • Dart 2.12.0

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.0.0, on macOS 11.0.1 20B50 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
```

Packages:

```
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  cloud_firestore:  ^0.14.0+2
  fluttertoast: ^7.0.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+7
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.10
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.3.1
  intl: ^0.16.1
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.0
  flutter_local_notifications: 1.4.4+4
  photo_view: ^0.10.2
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^1.0.0
  gpt_3_dart: ^0.0.1
  flutter_signin_button: ^2.0.0
  sign_in_with_apple: ^3.0.0
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.0.1
  crypto: ^2.1.5
  http: ^0.12.2
  meta:
```

Comment: Your dependancies in general are pretty outdated. But there's a conflict between ads and firestore, ads is using a newer API, so I would suggest updating your firestore at least.

Comment: getting same error